# How to open my app when I download a file with specific content-type from the browser, on android?

Tags: android, browser, manifest, content-type, intentfilter

I'd like to open my app when i download a file with specific mimeTipe, for example "application/pdf" using the browser.
I tried adding this intent-filter in the manifest app but it doesn't work.

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

Does the android browser send any intent that can help me to do that?
I don' want to open my app by clicking on the file, I need to do this reading the GET header response and opening the app according to the Content-Type of the header.

Comment: What happens when you download the file?  Does the browser simply download it, or does it open in another viewer?

Comment: At the moment it download the file and nothing else happens. I would like it opened my app while/after download instead. In the future I would like to call an other app that works on my file.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called an [Intent Filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ifs).  You can define a filter by file name, by URL, or by mime type.

In your case, Content-Type is a mime type.  A Mime example might look like this in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<intent-filter . . . >
    <data android:mimeType="video/mpeg" android:scheme="http" . . . /> 
    <data android:mimeType="audio/mpeg" android:scheme="http" . . . />
    . . .
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's what I'm trying to do but it doesn't work when I download the .pdf file. I miss something else maybe...